# Add,Sub,Multiply Arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am a begginer in C language , and i have to do a function to add , subtracting and multiplie two arrays and put it in another array.
In add function have to return false if occurs overflow.
In sub function have to return false if n1 is less than n2.
In multiply function have to return false if occurs overflow.
I have the following radix , first i full array with 0 and then number of smallest Weight is in the index 0. Example if i put 234 the BigInt will be index 79 0000...00234 index 0

```
#define MaxDigits 80

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef byte BigInt [MaxDigits];
```

This is what i have to add one:

```
   bool  addBigInt( const BigInt n1, const BigInt n2, BigInt res ){
        int carry=0;
        for(int i=0;i<80;++i){
           if(n1[i]+n2[i]>9){
              carry=res[i]%10;
           }
           res[i]=n1[i]+n2[i]+carry;    
       }

      if((n1[79]+n2[79]>9) ||(n1[78]+n2[78]>10 && n1[79]+n2[79]>8) ){
         return false;
      }
     else{
       return true;
     }
}
```

Sub one:

```
    bool  subBigInt(  const BigInt n1,  const BigInt n2, BigInt res ) {
        for(int i=0;i<80;++i){
            res[i]=n1[i]-n2[i];
         }
        for(int i=80;i>0;i--){
          if(n1[i]-n2[i]<0){
             return false;
         }
     }

      return true;
    }
```

I dont know realy know how to work with bools , if you can help me i would realy apreciate.
thank you

Comment: Declaration of 'BigInt' type?

Comment: #define MaxDigits 80 , typedef byte BigInt [MaxDigits];

Comment: You have `if((n1[80]+n2[80]>9)` but you only iterated `for(int i=0;i<80;++i)`

Comment: Oh thank you , i meant 79 because i have i=0 so the 80 position is 79

Comment: When doing arithmetic on any kind of big int array, you must contrive a **carry** from one element to the next. In the simplest case of addition, if there is a carry left over after the iteration, then you have an overflow.

Comment: So in each sum i have to see if is bigger than 10, and if is bigger i have to carry that to the next sum?

Comment: You only need to test the limits after the iteration. During it, the sum is `n1[i]+n2[i]+carry`. The next carry is `sum / 10`. The element value is `sum % 10`. Please put the **radix is 10** information in the question.

Comment: I have edited the sum function , what do you think? You need any information

Comment: Please don't edit the posted code to reflect any solution. How will anyone follow the comments? I have posted my suggestions as an answer, but it's still unclear how you set up the array, whether each element really is in the range 0..9.

Comment: Ok sorry. The range of numbers is 0..9 in each element

Comment: and now to see is there is overflow i just have to see the last if the last sum is bigger than 10?

Comment: Well yes, but that's in the carry left over, please see my answer. The multiplication will be quite similar, but the subtraction is the more difficult.

Comment: Ok , so it will be something like this if(carry>0){
                                               return false;
                                                    } , but how i know im analysing the last carry?

Comment: Have you even read my answer? That shows how to handle the final carry.

Comment: Yes i have read , but i dont understood if i put carry==0 , how can i see the last carry if it is bigger than 0?

Comment: You want your function to return `true` or `false`. If there is no carry left, `carry == 0` is `true` otherwise if there is a carry left then that comparison is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

For the addition, it could be like this

```
bool addBigInt( const BigInt n1, const BigInt n2, BigInt res ) {
    int i, sum, carry = 0;
    for(i=0; i<MaxDigits; i++) {
        sum = n1[i] + n2[i] + carry;    
        res[i] = sum % 10;
        carry = sum / 10;
    }
    return carry == 0;
}
```